# AppSync search not working anymore, but other querying functions are

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Months ago I created this graphql api and I added the searchable tag to some of my entities. Back then, the search function on AppSync was working perfectly fine, but after picking up my old project again it doesnt work even though other querying functions work.

[AppSync searchArtists doesn't work but listArtists does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LLTi.png)

In the photo I tried "matching" but I also tried eq, exists, mathPhrase, matchPhrasePrefix, multiMatch, ne, etc.

Comment: Its hard to help without seeing your resolver.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BmpTCqJTWDqRtJ_IzGQmGCds88b5m05w?usp=sharing
Hopefully this provides more context
@LeeroyHannigan